# How to set up the ACL to allow everyone list all the Users from the REST API

Tags: javascript, strongloop, loopbackjs

Im trying to list all the Users in my loopback 2.0 app using the REST API and I'm getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Authorization Required",
    "statusCode": 401,
    "stack": "...."
  }
}
```

I manually added the ACL to the model-config.json file:

```
"User": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "acls": [
        {
            "principalType": "ROLE",
            "principalId": "$everyone",
            "permission": "ALLOW",
            "accessType": "*"
        }
    ]
},
```

Since that failed, I created a model based on the User built-in model:

```
{
    "name": "Admin",
    "base": "User",
    "properties": {},
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {},
    "acls": [
        {
            "principalType": "ROLE",
            "principalId": "$everyone",
            "permission": "ALLOW",
            "accessType": "*"
        }
    ],
    "methods": []
}
```

But in the REST API I still have the same issue:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Authorization Required",
    "statusCode": 401,
    "stack": "....."
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help. =)

Comment: You can run the app with DEBUG=loopback:security:* node . to get the debug information for the ACLs. That may help.

Comment: @snathan thanks for the debug tip! That helped me see what was happening, there was another ACL with higher score, so I put an individual entry for "accessType": "READ" instead of "accessType": "*", and that gave my ACL a higher score.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. We should allow you to further configure the built-in model with additional ACLs. This is a todo for LoopBack.
2. You can subclass the built-in User model in common/user.json as you have illustrated.

   {
       "name": "user",
       "base": "User",
       "plural": "users"
   }

Then you need to expose it to REST by adding an entry to server/model-config.json, such as:

```
"user": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that we cannot extend the ACL of build-in models. My common/admin.json ended up like this:

    {
      "name": "Admin",
      "base": "User",
      "plural": "Admins",
      "properties": {},
      "validations": [],
      "relations": {},
      "acls": [
        {
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$everyone",
          "permission": "ALLOW",
          "accessType": "READ"
        }
      ],
      "methods": []
    }

Comment: It'd be great if the docs reflected this, b/c I'm coming in almost a year later and ran into the same issue w/o being warned in the docs about it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems loopback ppl allso hit that issue:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control/issues/8