# loopback3 coffeeshop tutorial: use curl to get reviewers

Tags: loopbackjs

In the above tutorial, reviews do not require an authorization token but coffeeshops do. And this works; I use curl to send email/password for a reviewer, receive an auth token and then send the auth token to get a list of shops.

But when I try the same to get a list of reviewers, I get an error of authorization required. Even though I sent an auth token.

Can someone explain this? What have I not understood?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to test this, but I'm pretty sure I'm correct.

`Reviewer` is [based](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started-intermediate/blob/master/common/models/reviewer.json#L3) on `User`, and **nobody is allowed to `find` all Users**.

In your scenario, you are authorized in the sense you have a token.  **This gives you the `$authenticated` role**, and if you have created anything probably the `$owner` role for those things.

If your next question is "**Can I allow `$authenticated` or `$everyone` to `find` all Users/Reviewers?**"  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353581/how-to-set-up-the-acl-to-allow-everyone-list-all-the-users-from-the-rest-api) question.

**Details**

You can see the difference in the access controls by looking at the [Review  model's ACLs](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started-intermediate/blob/master/common/models/reviewer.json#L3)

And look at [User's ACLs](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.json#L25)

Notice the User model uses the `$owner` role often (indicating you must be that User) and that it doesn't allow `find`, only `findById` for the `$owner`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Though it would be nice (from an admin perspective) to list all of the users.

Comment: Just to add I tried Reviewers/id-number and that worked.
interestingly, Reviewers/id-number/exists gave a requires auth error.
And trying with a different user id, having listed directly from the database, also gives an auth req error.

Comment: If you want to see exactly how loopback is deciding you can launch your server like `DEBUG=loopback:security:* node .` on linux/macos or `set DEBUG=loopback:security & node .` or windows